# How to select the most frequent value within a group (not all but only one)

Tags: sas

I have a data set with one grouping character variable x and one numeric variable y. For each value of x I want to select value of y that occurs the most, but for each value of x I want only one value of y (doesn't matter which one). I know how to select all such y for each x, but I don't know how to select only one.

```
proc sql;
    select x,y
    from (select x, y, count(*) as n_y
            from lab7.a
            group by x,y)
    group by x
    having n_y=max(n_y)
    ;
quit;
```

The code above gives me all such y for each x, but I would like to have only one y for each x.

I tried using order by n_y in a subquery and then select top 1, but apparently it doesn't work in sas. I also tried monotonic, but it adds number to rows to the whole query, it doesn't work within a group.

For example if I had data:

```
x y
A 1
A 2
A 2
B 1
B 2
C 3
C 3
```

my code will return

```
x y
A 2
B 1
B 2
C 3
```

but I would like

```
x y
A 2
B 1
C 3
```

or

```
x y
A 2
B 2
C 3
```

Comment: Do you care which you get, at all?  IE, is a biased solution acceptable (always pick min, always pick max, etc.)?

Comment: It's not that important. Preferably, I would like to get sth like the first (last) maximum that occurs, because that's the natural approach in most programming languages.

Answer (score 3):

Since SAS doesn't support the windowing functions or TOP X, I don't think it's technically doable in a single query.  You can probably use MONOTONIC() in conjunction with outer query, though:

```
  select x,y from (
    select x,y, monotonic() as m
    from (select x, y, count(*) as n_y
            from have
            group by x,y)
    group by x
    having n_y=max(n_y)
    )
    group by x
    having m=max(m)
;
```

Or

```
 proc sql;
  select x,max(y) from (
    select x,y
    from (select x, y, count(*) as n_y
            from have
            group by x,y)
    group by x
    having n_y=max(n_y)
    )
    group by x
;
quit;
```

That of course gives you a biased result - if you're okay with that, then that's fine.

If you're not, what I would do is take that SQL output which has two, then use `PROC SURVEYSELECT` to pick one at random (with `strata x` and `n=1`).

Comment: That's the kind of thing I got. For example, I can choose always just max(y) in a yet another outer query, but I was wondering if there is a "nicer" solution. Because in most languages it's usually easier to find one y rather than all of them, because that requires scanning the set twice

Comment: I don't know that it's actually easier in other languages- I suspect in many cases you're just not seeing the complexity.  SAS has better ways to do this that don't involve using SQL, though; sticking in PROC SQL is going to limit you some (as it's a relatively bare implementation of SQL).

Comment: If this is for a problem set, I'd be quite careful using MONOTONIC(), unless you're instructed to do so in other places.  MONOTONIC() is not documented and is considered not production quality - so many SAS shops will explicitly require code to not include it.

Comment: The perfect solution, I guess, would be if there was something that worked like MONOTONIC() but worked within a group, i.e. independently in each group. Since MONOTONIC() is no longer recommended, is there anything that works similarly?

Comment: @rafalpw No, and that's (mostly) by design.  SQL is never supposed to guarantee row order - so anything that's designed to get at the row order runs counter to that.  That's why the SQL standard added windowing functions.  SAS doesn't need that, because SAS has the data step, which does guarantee row order, and various procs which are superior versions of most of the rest of why you'd use windowing functions.  I'm not sure why SAS didn't implement `top n` - probably would make things less efficient, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

The better, non-SQL way, to do this is to use `PROC UNIVARIATE`.  The only restriction here is that it doesn't seem to work if *every* value is a mode (i.e., in your initial example, B has only 2 values, and both are modes).  But as long as you have enough values to make this question make any sense, this should work.

```
proc univariate data=have;
  by x;
  var y;
  output out=want mode=mode_y;
run;
```

That gives you the mode, and probably does so much faster than the `SQL` query.  It does require sorting by `x`, though, if it's not already.  It gives you the lowest mode by default.

Answer (score 1):

Why use `PROC SQL`?

```
 proc freq data=have ;
   tables x*y / noprint out=counts ;
 run;
 proc sort data=counts;
   by x descending count;
 run;
 data want ;
   set counts ;
   by x ;
   if first.x ;
 run;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have cleared that out in the beginning. This is from a problem list that I "have to" do in proc sql. I know how to do it without using proc sql.

Comment: I think the question is fine as presented, and non-sql answers should be fine - you're welcome to restrict accepts to SQL only, of course, but I don't think the answers should be restricted as such.  This ends up being a better question with better answers ignoring that restriction. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
proc sql;
select x,max(y) from table group by x;
quit;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run. And answers that sound like questions are often deleted in review,,,